# Angularjs ng-class expression syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help with the right syntax for the following `ng-class`-expression, the values are coming from a repeat search result.
Every value resolves right on its own, but the `ng-class` always resolve to `'tdgreen'`.

```
<td ng-class="{{searchResult|sumOfValue:'LastCount'}} < {{searchResult|sumOfValue:'Average'}} ? 'tdred' : 'tdgreen'">
```

Comment: Sorry my syntax was not posted
                <td ng-class="{{searchResult|sumOfValue:'LastCount'}} < {{searchResult|sumOfValue:'Average'}} ? 'tdred' : 'tdgreen'"><b>Total for {{lastmonth}}:</b> {{searchResult | sumOfValue:'LastCount'}}</td>

Comment: Use "edit" button for add additional information into your question.

Comment: not really clear what you are trying to do. Please explain intent of what your code should do. Also what does your filter do? A demo would help

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `ng-class` isn't meant to work with interpolation. Thats a good lesson to learn with angular - never mix evaluated directives and interpolation. The way you do it, you could just use the normal `class` attribute with the interpolation inside and it will work right away.

However, if u still want to use `ng-class`, you could write a wrapper function `$scope.sumOfValueAGreaterB(obj,a,b)` in your controller, which does your comparison and use the JSON-style ng-class feature to define your conditional classes, like:

```
<td ng-class="{tdred : sumOfValueAGreaterB(searchResult, 'Average', 'LastCount'),
tdgreen : sumOfValueAGreaterB(searchResult, 'LastCount', 'Average')}">
```

Another way would be to precompute the object passed to ng-class in your controller, but I dont think its a good fit in your situation as i am assuming you are doing this inside ng-repeat.

Also see [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#!) and [`$filter`-service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) documentation, in particular the `$filter`-service example plunker.